# extract the index from a value in an array

Tags: python

I want to know how I can extract the index of a value from a table. For example, I have this table (or matrix):

```
[ [1. 4. 1. 2.]
[2. 5. 3. 2.]
[0. 4. 4. 2.]
[3. 6. 5. 2.]
[7. 8. 6. 2.]
[11. 1. 7. 2.]
[10. 17. 7. 2.] ]
```

The value 8 is in line 4, how can I do with python to display this index (4)?

Comment: In case you're wondering, the downvotes are probably because you've posted your question but don't appear to have made any effort to solve it yourself. Please read [How to Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help you improve future questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to get the all indexes where 8 is in right?

So `4` in your example is the answer you want to get?

This code will return you the indexes of all occurences of 8:

```
myTable = [ [1, 4, 1, 2],
            [2, 5, 3, 2],
            [0, 4, 4, 2],
            [3, 6, 5, 2],
            [7, 8, 6, 2],
            [11, 1, 7, 2],
            [10, 17, 7, 2] ]

print ([(i)
   for i, myValue in enumerate(myTable)
   if 8 in myValue])
```

Comment: thank's @Philipp, that solved my problem :)

Comment: Good! Accept the answer please, so the question shows up as answered.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `numpy.where` to find the appearences of your number:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[1, 4, 1, 2], [2, 5, 3, 2], [0, 4, 4, 2], [3, 6, 5, 2], [7, 8, 6, 2], [11, 1, 7, 2], [10, 17, 7, 2]])
i, j = np.where(arr == 8)
```

`i` and `j` will hold arrays of locations of all 8's in your matrix. For your specific request you can use:

```
i[0] # OUTPUT 4
```